# django-mptt nested dropdown in standard ModelAdmin?

Tags: python, django, mptt

I'm using [django-mptt](https://github.com/django-mptt/django-mptt/) for a `Category` model, which is a foreign key to a `Project` model:

```
from django.db import models
from mptt.models import MPTTModel, TreeForeignKey

class Category(MPTTModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    parent = TreeForeignKeyY('self',
            null=True, 
            blank=True, 
            related_name='children'
            )

class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category')
```

It's easy to set up the `Category` admin using `MPTTModelAdmin`, complete with a nice nested dropdown for picking `parent` category:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from mptt.admin import MPTTModelAdmin
from myapp.models import Category, Project

admin.site.register(Category, MPTTModelAdmin)
```

Now I'd like to include a nice nested `Category` dropdown in my `Project` admin, but the standard `admin.ModelAdmin` does not include this functionality and subclassing `MPTTModelAdmin` doesn't seem to work:

> Project has no field named 'parent'

Is it possible to mimic the nested dropdown in a non-MPTT admin tool?

Comment: There is a typo "TreeForeignKeyY"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can still use `TreeForeignKey` on a non-`MPTTModel`, assuming that the linked model is an `MPTTModel`, i.e.:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    category = TreeForeignKey('Category')
```

Alternatively, you can make the field an instance of `mptt.forms.TreeNodeChoiceField` or `mptt.forms.TreeNodeMultipleChoiceField` on your form.